# Async/Await test with Jest not working in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, jestjs

I'm trying to test an `async` call with Jest in Node like this:

```
   it('testing to sign up feature', async (done) => {
        await expect(request(app).post('/signUp', {body:{a:1, b:3}})).resolves.toBe('created successful')
    });
```

However, it throws this error:

```
expect(received).resolves.toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: "created successful"
Received: {"header": {"connection": "close", "content-length": "18", "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8", "date": "Fri, 03 Jul 2020 09:35:39 GMT"}, "req": {"data": undefined, "headers": {"user-agent": "node-superagent/3.8.3"}, "method": "POST", "url": "http://127.0.0.1:53456/signUp"}, "status": 200, "text": "created successful"}

  70 | 
  71 |      it('testing to sign up feature', async (done) => {
> 72 |              await expect(request(app).post('/signUp', {body:{a:1, b:3}})).resolves.toBe('created successful')
     |
```

I'm not sure how I should mock the `text` of the response under `resolves.toBe...`

**EDIT**
Tried this

```
    const response = await request(app).post('/signUp', {body:{a:1, b:3}})
    expect(response).resolves.toEqual('created successful')
```

but this resulted in the same error

In case it's relavant. My signUp APIs look like this:

```
 signUp(req, res) {
    log.info('User signed up request received');
    postRequest('/signUp', JSON.stringify(req.body)).then((resp) => {
        res.status("200").send(resp);
    });
}



 async function postRequest(path, param) {
    try {
         return await mockCall(path, param);
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}



 function mockCall(path, param) {
        // A mimic
       const magicNumber = 2000;
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve("created successful");
            }, magicNumber);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I had solved.

```
it('testing to sign up feature', async (done) => {
        const f = await request(app)
            .post('/signUp')
            .send({body:{a:1, b:3}});
        expect(JSON.parse(f.text)).toEqual({ message: 'user created successfully', status: 200 });
        done();
    });
```

Also, noteworthy is the fact that I was using [`npm-nock`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock) to mock the calls.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    nock(<url>)
    .post('/signUp')
    .reply(200, { message: 'user created successfully', status: 200})
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

`request(app).post('/signUp', {body:{a:1, b:3}})` is a promise that is returning an object. You can assert on `.text`, instead of the entire object:

```js
it('testing to sign up feature', async (done) => {
  const response = await request(app).post('/signUp', {body:{a:1, b:3}})
  expect(response.text).toBe('created successful')
});
```

Comment: Tried changing as you suggested. Getting this error now:  ` expect(received).resolves.toBe()

    Matcher error: received value must be a promise

    Received has value: undefined `

Comment: Ah, `.resolves` is expecting a promise object. Removing that, should work. If you receive `created successful`, you know the promise has already resolved to retrieve the value. I updated the answer.

Comment: Actually This one and a variation of that I had already tried with this error: `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 30000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 30000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:` So I had changed it to that way.